# Assign value to Chartist chart value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chartist.js

Can someone help me solve this problem..
I'm trying to set **Chartist pie chart** data dynamically. I have a list of projects I'm displaying in a list. Each project has a chart with some information about the project like funding etc. When I try setting the "value" of my chartData, it refuses to detect my values as numbers. Below is an example:

```
//Chartist data object
fundingData: {
               series: [{
                          value: 0,
                          name: 'public funding',
                          className: 'some-class'                          
                        }, {
                           value: 0,     
                           name: 'private funding',

                        }]
              }

//param: project is an object I'm passing
        setChartData(project) {

               let x = Math.round(project.pro_amount); //
               console.log(x); // This prints the amount

               this.fundingData.series[0].value = x; // doesn't get assigned 

               this.fundingData.series[0].value = 12; // gets assigned 
             }
```

What am I doing wrong?.. hope my problem is clear enough

Comment: What display `this.fundingData.series[0].value` after assign `x`?

Comment: @Dabbbb It seems to reject the assignment.. So it doesn't display... But when I do something like... this.fundingData.series[0].value = x + 4.... It shows the value 4

Comment: can you put a `console.log( this.fundingData.series[0].value, x)` between assigns?

Comment: @Dabbbb sure.. Will try that

Comment: @Dabbbb. the value seems assigned but I get an infinite loop. This could more have to do with vuejs. Because the value only gets assigned with there is a console.log in the function which seems to cause an infinite loop. I'm confused. ;(

Answer (score 0):

Probably all is good, but Chartist isn't reactive. You must call `update` function after assign:
https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/api-documentation.html#chartistbase-function-update

Comment: I will take a look at that to see if it helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've decided to use Google charts and that seem to do what I want. Thanx for your efforts.